# How can I cause compilation to fail on warnings on CI and have extra rustflags set in .cargo/config?

Tags: rust, continuous-integration, rust-cargo

I’m trying to have Cargo fail on warnings on CI but not when developing locally.

I had a working solution which was to set `RUSTFLAGS=“-D warnings”` in the CI job. This worked well as it would indeed fail the build for the local crates but not the dependency crates (due to `—cap-lints`).

Recently, some rustflags had to be set in a (checked in) `.cargo/config` file:

```
[target.’cfg(target_os = “linux”)’]
rustflags = [“some”, “options”]
```

This didn’t work since `RUSTFLAGS` takes precedence and the `.cargo/config` flags would be ignored. I don’t want to add `-D warnings` to the `config` as this can be a pain when developing.

The current work around is a script that tweaks the `config` prior to the CI job:

```sh
sed -i "s:\(rustflags = .*\)]:\1, \"-D\", \"warnings\"]:g" .cargo/config
echo '[build]' >> .cargo/config
echo 'rustflags = [ "-D", "warnings"]' >> .cargo/config
```

This appends `-D warnings` to existing `rustflags` in the config *and* creates an extra catch-all `config` entry that makes sure that `-D warnings` is also enabled on non-Linux CI builds.

This is terribly hacky; is there a better solution I’m missing?

Maybe this should be a feature request on the Cargo repository but I don’t know what the ideal solution would look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`built::util::detect_ci()`](https://docs.rs/built/*/built/util/fn.detect_ci.html) to figure out if the current build is executed under CI. You can then use a small build script to set a cfg

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
build = true

[build-dependencies]
built = { version = "0.3", default_features = false }
```

**build.rs**

```
fn main() {
    if let Some(ci) = built::util::detect_ci() {
        // There may be a better way to do this
        println!("cargo:rustc-cfg=DENY_WARNINGS");
        println!("cargo:warning=Denying warnings because we are in CI \"{}\"", ci);
    }
}
```

Note that the result of the build script is cached, so once this build script has run and Cargo has decided whether we are running under CI or not, it will go with this result until you either modify the build script or `cargo clean`. This should not be a problem for either local development or CI unless Scotty beams you up on a regular basis.

**main.rs** or **lib.rs**

```
#![cfg_attr(DENY_WARNINGS, deny(warnings))]

fn main() {
    // This will be a warning locally but fail to compile e.g. if built on Travis
    Result::<(), ()>::Err(());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an environment variable override:

```bash
CARGO_BUILD_RUSTFLAGS='-D warnings' cargo check
```

If you're interested in details of how it works, use this: https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html#environment-variables  (in short, such environment variable names are generic, it's not just this variable name that has any effect).

If you run `cargo check` without the environment variable, it'll continue to compile even in presence of compilation warnings.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative solution, in order to separate "CI strict mode" and "local relaxed mode", you can simply use `clippy` in CI and `cargo check` locally. `clippy` can be easily configured to be "strict" and fail if there are warnings. It is also a great tool to ensure good code quality uniformly across the project.